# How to use JavaScript to check if a string contains certain keywords in an object

Tags: javascript, mysql, object

For example. I want to chcek, if my string message contains some keyword from MySQL Object(blacklist)

```
var message = "My keyword is blacklist";
```

MySQL Object

```
[
  { keyword: 'blacklist'},
  { keyword: 'some'},
  { keyword: 'other'},
  { keyword: 'words'},
]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store the information "does the message string contain at least one of the MySQL Object" in the "contains" boolean :

```js
var message = "My keyword is blacklist";

var contains = false;

var mysqlObject = [
  { keyword: "blacklist" },
  { keyword: "some" },
  { keyword: "other" },
  { keyword: "words" },
];

for (var i = 0; i < mysqlObject.length; i++) {
  if (message.includes(mysqlObject[i].keyword)) {
    contains = true;
  }
}

console.log(contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is following

```js
const message = 'My keyword is blacklist';
const blockedWords = [
  { keyword: 'blacklist'},
  { keyword: 'some'},
  { keyword: 'other'},
  { keyword: 'words'},
];
function isBlocked(message, blockedWords){
  for (const {keyword} of blockedWords){
      if (message.includes(keyword)){
         return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}

const result = isBlocked(message, blockedWords);

console.log(result);

console.log(isBlocked('Love JS', blockedWords));
```